# How to transform url in Python

Tags: python, url, encode, urllib

I have a string in python, which is a URL:

```
http://weibo.com\/p\/aa\/weibo?from=bb&wvr=5.1&mod=weibomore#cc
```

I want to a real URL that I can paste it in my chrome:

```
http://weibo.com/p/aa/weibo?from=bb&wvr=5.1&mod=weibomore#cc
```

Please tell me how to chang it **IN PYTHON**~~~

Comment: Fix how you got it in the first place.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams, there website is this...

Comment: Where did you get that string in the first place, though?

Comment: [replace](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=replace#str.replace) is not hard to find in the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you simply need to remove the backward slashes from your original string.

You can do that using `replace` as such..

```
url = string.replace("\\", "")
```

Answer (score 3):

`<your url string>.replace("\\","")` will do the trick, but as has been pointed out, it would be better to fix the source of this.

The solution will also remove any backquotes ("\"). Even legitimate ones - so it's not a general solution. Backslashes are allowed in urls*, [though its very unusual and causes problems](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-validator/2011Feb/0024.html)

*Then again perhaps not: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt - it looks like this is a confusing question.

Comment: This answer is wrong. The backslash is escaping the second quote. Also it replaces *all* backslashes, not just the ones that are a problem.

Comment: Yep, I fixed the quote issue. The solution will work for this specific URL, its certainly not beautiful or general.

Comment: You still didn't fix it, so I did. Also I don't think backslashes are allowed in URLs anyway, so this will work most of the time.

Comment: You're right. Looking at the edit history my edit was a typo, thanks for the fix.

Comment: @Doorknob backslashes in URLs are not strictly not allowed, it seems like the topic is a bit of a minefield.